# Axios get data not assignable to parameter of type SetStateAction

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-typescript, react-tsx

I'm building my first TypeScript app, having come from a JavaScript background.

I'm still getting my head around declaring types, but I have this current issue coming back.

My code is below, and the current error I'm getting is:

> Argument of type 'Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.

```
//interface File
export default interface InterfaceNameHere {
  author?: string;
  date?: number;
  title?: string;
  __v?: number;
  _id?: string;
  dataArray?: Array<IAnotherInterface>;
}

//component
const [returnedSearch, setReturnedSearch] = useState<InterfaceNameHere >({});

 useEffect(() => {
      axios
//NOTE: I have also tried .get<Promise<{data: InterfaceNameHere}>> and it still throws an error

        .get<Promise<AxiosResponse>>(
          `URLGOESHERE`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          setReturnedSearch(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          //error handling here
        });
  }, []);
```

I previously had `axios.get`, and of course it was working fine

But as I'm trying to declare the Type, it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the interface as the generic argument

```
axios.get<InterfaceNameHere>().then(...)
```